# Custom translationtool for .NET mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I'm creating a multi language application. The requirements for the functionality of the translation is more complicated then using the .resx files as I have tried.

I'm calling a webservice which returns a dataset with the required translations, these translation are then saved to a static class Translation. In this class I have a datatable, the dataset is transformed to objects and then added to the datatable.

So the datatable is like the dataset used in other tutorials. The problem comes in when I want the keywords in my view to be translated. The first thing I tried was declaring a list of keywords in my controller, translate these keywords and pass the dictionary in ViewData["Translations"]. This worked but this method isn't efficient enough.

In the example below it is possible to just call Multi.{Keyword} and the localization will select the correct file to be used to show the translated text.

### view

```
//street is a keyword in the resx file
@Html.LabelFor(c => c.name, Multi.Street)
```

### multibase

```
    public abstract class MultiBase : Controller
    {
        /*CLASS TO CHECK WHAT LANGUAGE IS 
         * SELECTED AND LOAD THE 
         CORRESPONDING LANGUAGE*/
        protected override void ExecuteCore()
        {
            string CultureName = null;
            string Language = null;
            HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["Language"];
            if (cultureCookie != null)
            {
                Language = cultureCookie.Value;
                switch (Language)
                {
                    case "English":
                        CultureName = "en";
                        break;
                    case "French":
                        CultureName = "fr";
                        break;
                    case "Dutch":
                        CultureName = "nl";
                        break;
                    default:
                        CultureName = "nl";
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CultureName = "en";
            }

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(CultureName);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            base.ExecuteCore();
        }

        protected override bool DisableAsyncSupport
        {
            get { return true; }
        }



    }
```

1 ) This way looks the most efficient way to go but how can I call the dictionary if the keywords aren't known inside the controller?

2 ) What is the best way to get the translations into my View? Quering inside the view doesn't seem a good idea... Calling a method translate("keyword") in the view and show the result as plain text, is this the way to go??

### Example

In the translation class is a method declared translate, this will return just one translated keyword.

```
 @Html.Label(keyword, translation.translate("keyword"));
```

3 ) Is there a way I can create a list of the keywords inside my cshtml list / controller and then return a dictionary or something to my view?

Thanks in advance for your help. If something is not clear, please put a comment and I will try to explain me furter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to re-think the design.

For example, every time you want a new language you'll have to change the switch in `ExecuteCore`. This is fundamentally at odds with [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles.

It would be better to store the culture code in the `cultureCookie` and then use that to create the `CultureInfo` - any exceptions can then use the default. That way you can remove the switch...

However, I would actually not use a cookie for holding language details because that won't be picked up by web crawlers. Google will only know your site is in one language. I would advise that you change the URL for each language rather than use cookies.

Comment: Storing the language would be like 'http://test.com?language=en' for example? That would be no problem, the piece of code I pasted was some test code I used to try the resx file. On what moment I should call the translation method and what is the most efficient way. Thx for responding so quickly

Comment: Yes, that is the kind of URL I'm talking about - or just test.com/en... You could, for example, put the lanugage code in the Application_BeginRequest method (Global.asax.cs).